# Lock record with something like an "Ignore update" trigger?

Tags: sql-server

I have a bit type field, "record_lock", which users can set freely.  The intention is that when record_lock=0 updates and deletions can be made, and when record_lock=1 they cannot.  The table has an AFTER UPDATE trigger which fires certain actions when different fields are updated using "IF UPDATE(field)" statements, and I wish to preserve this behaviour.

If I were to create a INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger, then it might look like:

```
UPDATE table
 SET field1=inserted.field1
     ...
     fieldx=inserted.fieldx
 FROM table INNER JOIN inserted ON table.ID=inserted.ID
 WHERE record_lock=0
```

But then *all* fields would be considered to have been updated by the AFTER UPDATE trigger.  I do not want this.  Or, I could do:

```
IF UPDATE(field1)
 UPDATE table
  SET field1=inserted.field1
  FROM table INNER JOIN inserted ON table.ID=inserter.ID
  WHERE record_lock=0;
...
IF UPDATE(fieldx)
 UPDATE table
  SET fieldx=inserted.fieldx
  FROM table INNER JOIN inserted ON table.ID=inserter.ID
  WHERE record_lock=0;
```

But then it fires multiple updates which also messes with the AFTER UPDATE and is likely to be less efficient.

What I really want to say is "fire the update as normal, but only for records where record_lock=0".  I haven't been able to find a way to do this.  It seems to require a level of trigger before even "INSTEAD OF UPDATE", perhaps "IGNORE UPDATE"!

Comment: What if someone wants to update the lock column?

Comment: You can use after update and rollback, but if someone updates multiple rows, some locked and some not, what would you expect to happen? It's all or nothing with transactions.

Comment: It sounds like you have created "trigger hell". This is sort of like the old school "dll hell" where everything is so reliant on everything else and firing in just the exact sequence that anything that disrupts the process or even tries to change it crashes the whole thing. Honestly, triggers should be used very sparingly as there are almost always better ways of handling data manipulation.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Replies in order: (a) If someone wants to update the lock column, then that must happen first as a separate update.  (b) Regarding multiple rows: I am intending to ignore only those which are locked when updating multiple records, but logging those ignored in another table for users to check.  However, I had considered that it might only be possible in an all or nothing capacity.  I could work with that. (c) Yes, with this project I have become aware that I should have used triggers more sparingly!  That said, they are a very appealing way of enforcing business rules.